# Can I create new S3 users and add IAM policies from the Linux command line?

Tags: amazon-s3, policies

Is there any good way of creating and managing S3 policies and users from the command line of my Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AWS Universal Command Line Tools](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli) are newer and better supported. They rely on Python, so if you can get Python for Raspberry Pi, you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience of using it myself, but I found a tool for interacting with Amazon IAM, the access control service for AWS, in a manner that might work for you:

**[IAM Command Line Toolkit](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/AWS-Identity-and-Access-Management/4143)** (note: last updated September 2010)

There may be more usable stuff under the [IAM Resources section](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/#resources).

If you are unfamiliar with IAM, [the documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/iam/) is one place to start. Although, knowing the general style of AWS documentation, there may be better resources and tutorials to be found elsewhere.